# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(\sin x)$ be a given function of $\sin x$.

How would I show that $\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you make the substitution $w = \pi-x$, so that $dw = -dx$, you get

\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx &= -\int_\pi^0 (\pi-w)f(\sin(\pi-w))dw \\
 &= \int_0^\pi (\pi-x)f(\sin(x))dx \\
 &= \pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin(x))dx - \int_0^\pi xf(\sin(x))dx
\end{align}
which gives the result you want.

Comment: Thanks, most appreciated. :)

Answer (score 8):

$\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx$

=$\int_0^\pi (\pi-x)f(\sin (\pi - x))dx$

= $\int_0^\pi (\pi-x)f(\sin x)dx$

= $\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx - \int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx$

$2\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)d$ =  $\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$

$\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)d$ =  $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$

I also used:  $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ =$\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

Comment: Its ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: there should be $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \sin xdx$.

Comment: @avatar: Thanks