# Computing the values of $ W_\alpha(n):=\int_0^\pi x^{\alpha-1}\sin(x)^{2n} $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Define the following integral as
$$
W_\alpha(n):=\int_0^\pi x^{\alpha-1}\sin(x)^{n}\,,\quad
V_\alpha(n):=\int_0^\pi x^{\alpha-1}\cos(x)^{n}
$$
where $n \in\mathbb{N}$.
Now in the base case $W_1(n)=W(n)$ this integral
simplifies into the well know Wallis integrals, and 
$V(n)=W(n)\,\forall\,n$. Which has been shown to be

> [$$\color{black}{W(n)
>          = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^n\mathrm{d}x 
>          = \left\{    \begin{array}{ll}    \frac{\pi}{2^{2p}} \binom{2p}{p}       & \text{if} \ \ n = 2p    \\
>      \frac{2^{2p+1}}{p+1} \big/ \binom{2p+1}{n} & \text{if} \ \ n = 2p +
>  1    \end{array} \right.}$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)

Through simmilar means one can also show that $V_2(2n)=W_2(2n)=\pi/2 W(2n)$. By using

[$$
\color{black}{
\int_0^\pi x R(\sin x,\cos^2x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi R(\sin x,\cos^2x)\,\mathrm{d}x
}
$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/evaluate-int-0-pi-xf-sin-xdx?rq=1)

This gives directly that 
$$
W_2(2n) = \int_0^{\pi} x \sin^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
        = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\pi} \sin^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
        = \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
        = \frac{\pi}{2}W(2n)
$$
as wanted, and exactly the same can be done for $V(n)$.
My question is:

- **Are there any more cases one can solve? When are they alike? Is there a general
  formula for $W_\alpha(n)$, $V_\alpha(n)$**

Comment: Note that $\sin^{2n}x$ and $\cos^{2n}x$ can be written as a finite sum of terms of type $\sin k x$, $\cos k x$ with $k=0,\ldots, 2n$. The remaining integrals can be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function $_1F_2$. For example: 
$$\int_0^{\pi}x^{\alpha-1}\cos kx\,dx=\frac{\pi^{\alpha}}{\alpha}{}_1F_2\left[
\begin{array}{c} \alpha/2 \\
1/2,1+\alpha/2
\end{array};-\frac{\pi^2 k^2}{4}\right]$$
So a general formula exist for both $W_{\alpha}(n)$, $V_{\alpha}(n)$.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar   I am also started to look into these... I was doing this by using a  recurrent relation. Did you figured it out already? What if you have something like \[ \int_{0}^\pi x^{\alpha}cos^m(x)sin^n(x) dx \]? This is something I am trying to figure out... Let me know if you have already done it.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Actually the formula turned out pretty nice after you convert everything into exponential!!