# Problematic integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate $$\int_0^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}\ dx\ ?$$ I wish I could say I ran out of ideas, but actually I have none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the change of variables $x\rightarrow\pi-x$ and add the two results:
$$2I=\int_0^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}\ dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}\ dx=\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}dx.$$
I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/evaluate-int-0-pi-xf-sin-xdx?rq=1) and thought about that. Easy.

Comment: @Jules Yes, this is a rather standard trick. It remains to make a further change of variables $y=\cos x$ and you are done.

Comment: May the downvoter explain his problem with this answer?

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter doesn't realise why the last integral is easier (the Weierstrass substitution).

Comment: Actually, as O.L. noticed, you don't even need Weierstrass substitution.