# Prove integral equality $ \int_{0}^{\pi} xf(\sin(x))dx = \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(x))dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-writing

How can I prove the following claim for any given continues function:

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} xf(\sin(x))dx = \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(x))dx
$$

Thanks!

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/evaluate-int-0-pi-xf-sin-xdx

Comment: @OlivierOloa, I didn't change the Question. What title u r talking about?

Comment: The duplicate only gives the first part of the answer, right?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: IMO this is no  duplicate because the RHS reads $\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and not $\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi}$

Comment: Please add context to the post: what is the background of the question? Where did you encounter it? Is it useful for solving other mathematical problems? Posts that contain nothing but a problem statement are discouraged, and are often put on hold for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\int_0 ^ {\frac{\pi}{2}} f(\sin x)dx = \int_0 ^{\pi} f(\sin x)dx $$
Let $$I = \int_0^ {\pi} \left(xf(\sin x) - \frac{\pi}{2} f(\sin x)\right)dx $$ 
$$I = \int_0 ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x-\frac{\pi}{2}) f(\sin x)dx$$
Using the substitution $u = \pi - x $ and the fact that $\sin(\pi-x) =\sin x$ gives $I = -I$ 
Thus $I =0$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} xf(\sin(x))dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} xf(\sin(x))dx +\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} xf(\sin(x))dx \\
= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} xf(\sin(x))dx +\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\pi-x)f(\sin(x))dx .
$$