# Can I factorize this out?

Tags: integration

I was trying to prove the identity: 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} {xf(\sin(x))} dx =  \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} {f(\sin(x))}$$
Firstly, I substitute $x=\pi - t$.
Then:
$dx=-dt$ and substitute that into the integral, I get:
$$I=-\int_{\pi}^{0} \pi f(\sin(\pi - t)) - tf(\sin(\pi-t))dt.$$ 
After that I get:
$$I +\int_{0}^{\pi} tf(\sin(t)) dt=\int_{0}^{\pi} \pi f(\sin(t)) dt $$
So, can I factorize the LHS of the equation to let it become 2I, and I can prove the expression, if it can be factorized, why? The variables are different.

Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/evaluate-int-0-pi-xf-sin-xdx

Comment: I see, thank you very much. The problem is solved.

Comment: No! the looks are deceptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By shifting the argument,

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} {xf(\sin(x))} dx =  \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} {f(\sin(x))}$$

becomes

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)f(\cos(x))} dx =  \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {f(\cos(x))}dx$$

which is true because $xf(\cos(x))$ is an odd function.

Comment: So, the reason why it is true is that $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {xf(cos(x))} dx =0 $ due to the fact that the limits are the same.

Comment: @HenryCai: you probably mean *opposite*.

Comment: I changed my comment, is this right? Due to the fact that cos(x) is an odd function. So, the limits are the same.

Comment: @HenryCai: $\cos x$ is an even function.

Comment: Sorry, due to the fact that cos(x) is an even function, so cos(-x)=cos(x) so, the integral $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} xf(cos(x)) dx$ would be equal to 0. However, there is x, x is not an even function, so, it does not equal to 0...I am quite confused, would you mind to explain this part to me?

Comment: @HenryCai: it is precisely because $x$ is odd that the integral is zero.