# Is $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {xf(\sin{x})} = 0$ if $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I've tried writing this integral as sum of two integrals, the first integral on the interval $[-\pi/2, 0]$ and the second one on $[0, \pi/2]$ and then tried showing that the sum of these integrals is equal to 0. I've tried with variable substitution, but neither of my attempts gave results and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Are there any other constraints on $f$? If not, it trivially fails in general, because e.g. we can force the integrand to be positive for $|x|\in(0,\,1]$.

Comment: @J.G. I actually just realized that I had misunderstood a notation in the book. But I'll post a new question for that, because initially I was trying to solve the problem of this post.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac{1+x}2$ ?

Comment: It turns out there is already an answer that I couldn't find on google for the real problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/evaluate-int-0-pi-xf-sin-xdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=0$ for $-\pi/2\leq x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0<x\leq\pi/2$, the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}xdx>0$.